# $f(A)$ is invertible iff characteristic polynmoial and f have no common root

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following theorem.

> Let $A$ be a square matrix, and let $p_A(t)$ be its characteristic polynomial. Let $f(t)$ be a given polynomial. Then $f(A)$ is invertible iff $p_A$ and $f$ have no common root.

First Let me state what I know. 
Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix.  Then $p_A(t) = det(A-tI_n)$ and $f(t) = c_0 + c_1 t^1 + \cdots c_n t^n + \cdots$ is polynomial of $t$.

Comment: Common root in $\mathbb{C}$, possibly. A rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $90$ degrees has characteristic polynomial $x^2+1$, which has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$; but $A^2+I = 0$ is not invertible, even though $x^2+1$ does not have any roots in common with $p_A$ (because the latter has no roots in this field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working over $\mathbb{C}$.

The roots of the characteristic polynomial are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$; that is, the scalars $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is **not** invertible.

Factoring $f(x)$ into linear terms you have
$$f(x) = c(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_k).$$
IF $f(x)$ and $p_A$ have no common roots, then $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ are **not** eigenvalues. So $A-a_iI$ is invertible for each $i. Thus,
$$f(A) = c(A-a_1I)\cdots(A-a_kI)$$
is a product of invertible matrices, and thus is itself invertible.

Conversely, if $f(A)$ is invertible, then each $A-a_iI$ is invertible, which you can verify by taking determinants. Thus, none of the $a_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$, and so none of them are roots of $p_A$.

Comment: I have a question "If $f(x)$ and $p_A$ have no common roots, then $a_1,\cdots a_k$ are not eigenvalues. So $A−a_i I$ is invertible for each  i"

How one can show that?

Comment: @phy_math: The eigenvalues are **precisely** the scalars $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible. I say so in the immediately preceding paragraph. If $a_i$ is an eigenvalue, then not invertible; if it is **not** an eigenvale, then invertible.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose everything happens in the field of complex numbers.
Write $f$ as a product of linear factors,
$$
f = c (t-\mu_1) \cdots (t-\mu_k)
$$
with $c\ne0$.
Then 
$$
\det( f(A)) = \det( c (A-\mu_1 I_n) \cdots (A-\mu_k I_n)) 
=c^n \det(A-\mu_1 I_n) \cdots \det(A-\mu_k I_n)
$$
is zero iff one of the factors is zero, that is, if one of the roots of $f$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

in $\mathbb C$, if you know typical proofs of Cayley Hamilton this should be immediate.

*idea 0:*
suppose your matrix $A$ is upper triangular

*idea 1:*
upper triangular matrix times upper triangular matrix = upper triangular matrix
(i.e. closure under multiplication)
by direct computation

*idea 2:*
upper triangular matrix plus upper triangular matrix = upper triangular matrix
(i.e. closure under addition)
obvious

*idea 3:*
let $p_A$ have roots $\lambda_k$
then $f(A)$ has $f(\lambda_k)$ on the diagonal (immediate when you make use of prior ideas), and $f(\lambda_k)=0$  iff $\lambda_k$ is a root of $f$, by definition

*idea 4*
a triangular matrix is invertible *iff* it has no zeros on the diagonal.  This proves the claim for triangular matrices.

The 'more general' case comes immediately because in $\mathbb C$ every n x n matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix (Jordan, Schur triangularization, or other more basic approaches), and rank doesn't change by similarity transforms and neither does the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof which also works in another context (field extensions).

If $f$ and $p_A$ have no common roots, that means there are coprime. [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm) says that if $f$ and $p_A$ are coprime, then there exist polynomials $u$ and $v$ such that $uf + vp_A = 1$. Now plug in $A$:

$$
I = u(A) f(A) + v(A) p_A(A) = u(A) f(A).
$$