# Characteristic polynomial, $f(0) \neq 0$ iff $T$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to prove the following theorem

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$. Then $f(0) \neq 0$ iff $T$ is invertible.

It seems this question is related with my previous questions [$f(A)$ is invertible iff characteristic polynmoial and f have no common root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529080/fa-is-invertible-iff-characteristic-polynmoial-and-f-have-no-common-root)

I think I can change $T$ to be matrix $A$, and set characteristic polynomial $f(t) = det(A - t I_n)$, then clearly $f(0) = det(A) $ so $det(A)\neq 0$ iff $A$ is invertible.

Is this the right process? Without introducing $A$, how one can show this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any polynomial $f$ with  leading coefficient $1$ the constant term $f(0)$ is the product of the roots. In this case the $f(0) \neq 0$ iff the product of the eigen values is not $0$ iff $0$ is not an eigen value off $T$ is invertible,