# Solution Check: If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $A^3=2I$, show that $B=A^2-2A+2I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

> $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices which its entries are real numbers. If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and we know $A^3=2I$, prove that $B=A^2-2A+2I$ is an invertible matrix.

Here's my approach:

$B=A^2-2A+2I$, multiplying by $-A$ from the left side gives $$-A B=-A^3+2A^2-2A.$$ Substituting $A^3$ by $2I$ gives $$-AB=-2I+2A^2-2A=2(A^2-A-I).$$ Hence $$(-\dfrac{A}{2}B)=(A^2-I)-A=(A-I)(A+I)-A.$$ Substituting $I$ by $\dfrac{A^3}{2}$ gives $$(\dfrac{A}{2}B)=(A-\dfrac{A^3}{2})(A+\dfrac{A^3}{2})-A=A\left[(I-\dfrac{A^2}{2})(I+\dfrac{A^2}{2})-I\right].$$ Multiplying by $\dfrac{A^2}{2}$ from the left gives $$(-\dfrac{A^3}{4}B)=\dfrac{A^3}{2}\left[(I-\dfrac{A^2}{2})(I+\dfrac{A^2}{2})-I\right]$$ and substituting $A^3$ by $2I$ gives $$-\dfrac{B}{2}=(I-\dfrac{A^2}{2})(I+\dfrac{A^2}{2})-I=I-\dfrac{A^4}{4}-I=-\dfrac{A^4}{4}=-\dfrac{2A}{4}=-\dfrac{A}{2}.$$ So $A=B$. And we know $$A(\dfrac{A^2}{2})=(\dfrac{A^2}{2})A=I,$$ so $A$ is invertible. It shows that $B$ is also invertible.

Comment: $AB=BA$   because $B$  is a polynomial in $A$

Comment: @WillJagy is his approach wrong?

Comment: @4bolfazl  longer than needs be. If $J,K$  square matrices are both polynomials in some $M$   then $JK = KJ$

Comment: @WillJagy His knowing are insufficient for this

Comment: arguably a duplicate of:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529080/fa-is-invertible-iff-characteristic-polynmoial-and-f-have-no-common-root/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = B$ is not even true. If it was eigenvalues of $A$ would satisfy two equations $x^3-2$ and $x^2 - 3x +2$ which don't even have common roots.

To solve your question do some polynomial division and note that

$x^3 - 2 = (x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2) + 2x -6$

Thus

$(A + 2I)B = -2A + 6I$

Hence $B$ will be invertible as long as $A -3I$ is. For this multiply by $A^2 + 3A + 9I$ and use $A^3 = 2I$.

Comment: Which part of my proof is wrong? I think $A=B$ is true and you cannot behave with matrices like numbers.

Comment: Some times you can. You just have to know when and when not. $A = B$ is not true. As a simple counter example take $A = 2^{1/3}I$.

Comment: As far as 'where is your solution wrong' concerned then for now you should try to figure it out. If not ask again tomorrow I will see. Right now it's late night here.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I followed your instructions and got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a comment about your solution, but a remark how to attack this more generally with much less computation.

*Lemma*: Let $f,g \in K[T]$ be two polynomials which are coprime. If $R$ is a $K$-algebra and $a \in R$ satisfies $f(a) = 0$, then $g(a)$ is invertible.

Proof: With the extended Euclidean algorithm we find polynomials $u,v \in K[T]$ with $u \cdot f + v \cdot g = 1$. Plug in $a$. Since $f(a)=0$, we get $v(a) \cdot g(a) = 1$, and of course also $g(a) \cdot v(a) = 1$ since both are polynomial expressions in $a$. $\quad \square$

We can apply this here to $K = \mathbb{R}$, $R = M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $f = T^3 - 2$, $g = T^2 - 2 \cdot T + 2$. The Euclidean algorithm yields indeed
$$10 = -(T+1) \cdot f + (T^2+3T+4) \cdot g$$
So just to repeat the argument in this special case: Since $f(A)=0$ by assumption, we get $(A^2+3A+4) g(A) = 10$, so $g(A)$ is invertible.

*Remark.* The converse of the Lemma is also true. Assume that $f,g \in K[T]$ have the property $f(a) = 0 \implies g(a) \in R^{\times}$ for all $K$-algebras $R$ and its elements $a \in R$. Then $f,g$ are coprime. We just have to apply the asumption to $R := K[T]/\langle f \rangle$ and the element $a := [T]$.

Answer (score 2):

Others answers are solving the exercise instead of answering your question.

You made a mistake in the step

$$(A-\dfrac{A^3}{2})(A+\dfrac{A^3}{2})-A=A\left[(I-\dfrac{A^2}{2})(I+\dfrac{A^2}{2})-I\right]$$

If you factor $A$ from each factor in the LHS you get

$$(A-\dfrac{A^3}{2})(A+\dfrac{A^3}{2})-A=A^2(I-\dfrac{A^2}{2})(I+\dfrac{A^2}{2})-A = A\left[A(I-\dfrac{A^2}{2})(I+\dfrac{A^2}{2})-I\right]$$